# network.target stays dead, causing troubles for dnsmasq.service

Tags: systemd, services, systemd-networkd

I'm having issues with `dnsmasq.service`, caused by `network.target`

I've seen people having problems with `network.target` but for them it was caused by `network-online.target`. But it works fine for me

```
● network-online.target - Network is Online
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/network-online.target; static)
     Active: active since Sun 2023-08-06 23:03:46 CEST; 19h ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
             https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE

Aug 06 23:03:46 rasberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target network-online.target - Network is Online.
```

Here's the dnsmasq `systemctl status dnsmasq.service` command:

```
○ dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Aug 07 18:18:59 rasberrypi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Aug 07 18:18:59 rasberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Job dnsmasq.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Here's the `systemctl cat dnsmasq.service`:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service
[Unit]
Description=dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
Requires=network.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid

# Test the config file and refuse starting if it is not valid.
ExecStartPre=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq checkconfig

# We run dnsmasq via the /etc/init.d/dnsmasq script which acts as a
# wrapper picking up extra configuration files and then execs dnsmasq
# itself, when called with the "systemd-exec" function.
```

As this uses 1 dependency, `network.target`.

Here's the `systemctl status network.target`

```
○ network.target - Network
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/network.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
             https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE

Aug 06 23:03:46 rasberrypi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for network.target - Network.
Aug 06 23:03:46 rasberrypi systemd[1]: network.target: Job network.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Aug 07 18:18:59 rasberrypi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for network.target - Network.
Aug 07 18:18:59 rasberrypi systemd[1]: network.target: Job network.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

I can't get it to (re)start

```
Failed to restart network.target: Operation refused, unit network.target may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status network.target' for details.
```

The last thing that I wanted to share *(for this moment)* is the

```
# /lib/systemd/system/network.target
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Network
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Documentation=https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE
After=network-pre.target
RefuseManualStart=yes
```

After reading I see the `RefuseManualStart=yes`, But why doesn't it start automatically?
Even my good *friend* ChatGPT can't even help me